# How does reshape know about a non-existent row?

Tags: r

I have the following code in R:

```
base_historicals <- sqldf("
  select
    date,
    case when channel is null then 'Unknown' else channel end as channel,
    phone,
    count(*) as sales
  from
    transaction_phones as t
  left join
    acquisition as a
  on
    t.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
  where
    phone != 'droid'
  group by
    date,
    case when channel is null then 'Unknown' else channel end,
    phone
")

# Reshape the historicals to be what we need for HTS

base_historicals <- melt(base_historicals, id=c("phone","channel","date"), measured=c("sales"))
base_historicals <- cast(base_historicals, date ~ phone + channel, sum,  add.missing = TRUE)
```

I would expect this to give me a data frame with one column per phone/channel combination, one row per day, and the appropriate sales figures in each cell. I use the add.missing parameter, because I want `reshape` to assume that, if there are missing combinations of phones/channels/dates, it should fill those cells in with zeros.

The weird thing is that I'm getting columns for the `droid` phone, even though I've explicitly filtered it out of my data frame!

Verifying with sqldf proves it's not in there.

`sqldf('select distinct phone from base_historicals')`, run after the first sqldf call will return a list of all phones - and the droid is not in there. But as soon as I call the `reshape` functions, it shows up!

How in the world does `reshape` know about a value that doesn't even exist in the data frame? How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: My guess is that is that `phone` is a factor variable. What do you get when you type `levels(dat$phone)` with the appropriate variable and data.frame names? If you see droid as a level, all you have to do is relevel the factor: `dat$phone<-factor(dat$phone)`

Comment: Mind = blown. Thank you, sir.

Comment: no problem. cool username; love byzantine history.